# Spend and unspent

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

[image]
Please I sent btc to a particular wallet, initially it was both showing unspent but I only see one spent now what does it mean?[image]

Comment: It means the person to whom you sent the funds has spent them - either sending them to another person, or to a different wallet of their own.  (There is no way to know which.)

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have spent (sent to another receiver or address ) one of the two funds and the transaction spending this one fund has been included in a block and recorded on the blockchain and this doesn't belong to you anymore. The other unspent fund belongs to you and you can use it whenever you want.

P.S: If the wallet to which you sent the funds belongs to you.

To know more about this explore how UTXO in bitcoin works.